# Python Matplotlib: "ImportError: cannot import name flatten"

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 and am trying to use the python library `matlibplot`. I installed it via `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` and this seemed to be successful. However, then I try to run a python script with `import matplotlib`, I get the following exception message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./simulate.py", line 6, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 20, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/colors.py", line 54, in <module>
    import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 34, in <module>
    import new
  File "/home/rob/Dropbox/Fourth Year/algo/git/new.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 219, in <module>
    from cbook import flatten, is_string_like, exception_to_str, \
ImportError: cannot import name flatten
```

This has happened previously (and I was not able to get around it). There does not seem anyone who has had the same problem.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had a file called `new.py` in the same directory.

Its worth noting that you need to remove that and `new.pyc` to fix the issues.

Comment: Good catch.  You've taught me to actually read the file names in tracebacks.